# Can I say "Hoping for good"? And some other songwriting problems

Tags: informal-language, lyrics

I'm writing a song with the following draft lyrics:

> My little soul, don't be so blue
> This little song is made to be happy,
> My tall body, don't be so shy:
> There are just two of us here: you and I.
>
> There are just two of us waiting for something,
> There are just two of us hoping for good,
> There are just two of us secretly dancing,
> There are just two of us misunderstood
>
> There are just all of us waiting for something,
> There are just all of us hoping for good,
> There are just all of us secretly dancing,
> There are just all of us misunderstood

I believe there are some problems:

1. This little song is made [for you] to be happy — is it acceptable to omit 'for you' here? Does it make any sense?
2. You and I — I know that it's not grammatically correct yet widely used. But is it critical or totally normal?
3. Hoping for [something] good [to happen] – again, is it understandable without the words in brackets?
4. There are just all of us — is it possible to say so?

Many thanks!

Comment: When it comes to song lyrics, you can write what you like. If you're in doubt, try them on a  couple of friends. Song lyrics are sometimes completely impenetrable, expressing something inside the writer that's not obvious to the rest of the world.

Comment: Since you are writing a song, I think it might be helpful to know that "there are" is used in the formal language and "there's" is what you would usually hear in songs, movies and casual conversations. See: ell.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/theres-vs-there-are